# Editing with Chrome Developer Tools - Uncaught Syntax: Cannot use import statement outside of a module

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ecmascript-6, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to use Chrome Developer Tools Filesystem Editing feature in the latest version of Chrome (78.0.x) and Chrome is highlighting my first import and giving me the error `Uncaught Syntax: Cannot use import statement outside of a module`.

These files are perfectly fine and being used correctly (with `type="module"`) in the real code (the files are literally running in the browser part of the window right next to it).

This is problematic for two reasons:

- It is simply annoying for it to tell me every one of my files has an error.
- More importantly, it stops highlighting errors after the first one, and since it is highlighting the first line of every file, it won't highlight any real errors for me.

Is there any way for me to either tell Chrome that "hey, these are modules" or "hey, shut up about this specific error"?

[image]

**Note:** This is **not** about getting the error in general. This is specifically about it appearing while editing files on my file system inside of Chrome Developer Tools with the filesystem option. I tried searching for this specific issue but never found anything about it.

Comment: I encounter this error occasionally 1% of time so I guess it's a bug in devtools filesystem mappings because my project's webpack config doesn't change.

Comment: Just to note: I'm not using Webpack but polymer's build tool, though same idea. Interesting that you sometimes don't see it. I wonder if there is a file or files Chrome will check to realize it shouldn't be blowing up... hmm...

Comment: Wait, this definitely happens like maybe 10% of time when reloading the extension in a project without any bundler/compiler, in which I'm using the native ES Imports. As for the webpack, I'm not sure anymore I ever saw this error there.

Comment: I think the other comments do not really realise whats the problem so i opned a issue in chrome to get that solved as i also see no way to indicate that i am using module syntax i think it simply is a missing thing: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1208314

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in the newer Chrome versions and was happening from version 70-90

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1202495

It should work now